# Facebook SDK / Graph Api: retrieve updated time (date set on timeline)

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook PHP SDK to display my fan page feeds on my website with the date using this :

```
echo "<p>" . date("m-d-Y", (strtotime($post['created_time']))) . "</p>";
```

My problem is that "created_time" shows the creation date, but I want to show **the date displayed on my timeline** : **for some post I have used the function "change date"** (on the top right corner) so the post will display (and also go on the timeline to) -let say- December 1st even though I have created the post today (January 2nd). So on my Facebook timeline everything is okay. But what  should be the code for my php sdk ?

I have also tried "`updated_time`" but I am getting the time of the last comment not the "updated created date".

Any idea how I can solve this?

Thanks a lot !

update : what I want to retrieve is the attribut data-utime (from facebook HTML) but what is the array in graph API corresponding to this data ?

Comment: Sounds like it has to do with different timezones. Facebook added support for different timezones in August, 2012. https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/08/01/platform-migration--events-timezone-support/

Comment: Thanks for your help durrrutti! I am sorry I have misleading you with start_time (I just realized it's for event not post). I found that the data ( date displayed on timeline after I use the function "change date") I want to retrieve is under the attribut data-utime (from facebook HTML). I try this in my code but it still not working. There must be an array in graph API storing this data but which one !? Any idea?